# Type Object is not assignable to type 'Object[]

Tags: angular2-services, angular2-observables

I don't understand returning type to format on Observer :

This is my observer :

```
return new Observable (observer => {

        this.http.get('myurl').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(

            data => {

                observer.next(data);
                observer.complete();

            },
            error => {

                observer.error(error);
                observer.complete();

            }

        );

    });
```

And my controller

```
this.competService.getAll().subscribe(
        data => {

            data.forEach((item) => {
              mylist.push(item);
            });

        },
        error => {

            this.busy = false;
            this.authService.errors(error);

        }


    );
```

And i have always the same error :

```
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Object[]'
```

Any body can help me please ?

Comment: At what line do you have it?

Comment: on `data.forEach((item) => {
              mylist.push(item);
            });`

Comment: what is return type of `competService.getAll` and what is type of `mylist`?

Comment: getAll is the function observer (at top of my question). Data is a simple json array of object. I dont know can i precise the type returned in my observer

Comment: Try to reproduce the problem in typescript's [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html) then share the link.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify the type that is returned from your HTTP request, the HTTP client assumes it's an Object. This is causing the type mismatch error that you are seeing. You are trying to assign type Object to type `any[]`. You can specify the return type by doing

```
this.http.get<any[]>(this.ROOT_URL).subscribe(...);
```

Source: [Type object is not assignable to type any[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47513945/type-object-is-not-assignable-to-type-any)