# Type object is not assignable to type any[]

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using PrimeNG datatable. I using httpClient in Angular to fetch some mock data from JSON Placeholder. It appears in my console as an array of objects, however the Visual Studio Code error is saying it is an object. The error says 'type Object is not assignable to any[].' What is the problem here?

table-layout.component.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { Component, OnInit, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table-layout',
  templateUrl: './table-layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table-layout.component.css']
})

export class TableLayoutComponent implements OnInit {

  ROOT_URL: string = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
  results: any[]

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData() {
    this.http.get(this.ROOT_URL).subscribe(data => {
      this.results = data
      console.log(this.results) //this is an array in the console 
    })
  }

}
```

table-layout.component.html

```
<p-dataTable [value]="results">
</p-dataTable>
```

Comment: show us the getData() Code. maybe is because u are returning another type of data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you do not specify the type that is returned from your http request, the http client assumes its an `Object`. This is causing the type mismatch error that you are seeing. You are trying to assign type `Object` to type `any[]`. You can specify the return type by doing

```
this.http.get<any[]>(this.ROOT_URL).subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
return this.http.get<any>(this.url)
```

Use any in service